# Finding from-to distances from a matrix (matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, distance

The following matrix a represents a from-to distance:

```
a = [0 3 5 6; 4 0 2 9; 9 1 0 4; 8 3 8 0];

a =

 0     3     5     6
 4     0     2     9
 9     1     0     4
 8     3     8     0
```

(I.e. From 2 To 4 = 9, From 1 To 2 = 3, etc.)

matrix ***a*** is static(not changing) and there is another matrix ***b*** which changes. An example input is:

```
b = [1; 4; 2; 1; 3; 4; 1];

b =

 1
 4
 2
 1
 3
 4
 1
```

I am looking to find the distance between the first row and the second row -- and perform that task for all rows to output:

```
b =

 1  
 4  6
 2  3
 1  4
 3  5
 4  4
 1  8
```

Where the second column is the value obtained from matrix ***a***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one line solution:

```
%#Set parameters of problem
a = [0 3 5 6; 4 0 2 9; 9 1 0 4; 8 3 8 0];
b = [1; 4; 2; 1; 3; 4; 1];
aSize = size(a);

%#The one-line solution 
Soln = [b, [NaN; a(sub2ind(aSize, b(1:end-1), b(2:end)))]];
```

Alternatively, the non-vectorized solution is:

```
%#Set parameters of problem
a = [0 3 5 6; 4 0 2 9; 9 1 0 4; 8 3 8 0];
b = [1; 4; 2; 1; 3; 4; 1];
T = length(b);

%#Preallocate a distance vector
bDist = NaN(T, 1);

%#Loop over b getting the distance for each pair
for t = 2:T
    bDist(t, 1) = a(b(t-1), b(t));
end

%#Combine b and bDist into a single matrix.
Soln = [b bDist];
```

So which solution is optimal? On my machine (R2012b, Linux Mint v12), the tipping-point length of `b` is about 650. If `b` is larger than 650, then use the vectorized solution (ie the one-liner). If `b` is smaller than 650, then use the loop.

By the way, if you are wondering, the one-line solution works by converting the successive pairs in `b` into row and column indices for the matrix `a` by using the `sub2ind` function. The solution vector is then found by indexing `a` using these indices.

ps An asymmetric distance matrix? Sounds like an interesting problem!

Comment: Great! Thank you! The one-line solution make it look so simple.

Comment: @Geoff Glad to help. If you're satisfied with my answer, then the best thanks is to mark the question answered by clicking the tick-box. :-)